# Symfony вывод данных из бд в формате json

Tags: php, json, symfony, symfony3

Здравствуйте.

(Symfony) требуется вывести данные из mysql в формате json.

Получаем статью

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$posts = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:Post')->findBy([], ['id' => 'DESC'], 1);
```

В формат json

```
return new JsonResponse($posts);
```

В данный момент выводит `[{}]`. Мне нужно запихнуть все данные статьи (title, description и т.д.) в массив и вывести с помощью `JsonResponse`. Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Объект в JSON-строке пустой, так как объект класса Post содержит приватные свойства, которые не могут быть прочитаны функцией json_encode.

Попробуйте написать так:

```
$post = $this->getDoctrine()
             ->getRepository('BlogBundle:Post')
             ->createQueryBuilder('p')
             ->select('p')
             ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
             ->setMaxResults(1)
             ->getQuery()
             ->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

return new JsonResponse($post);
```

Comment: Все свойства всех сущностей приватные в Symfony

Answer (score 0):

```
  $postRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('BlogBundle:Post');
  $post = $postRepository->findAll();

  $response = new JsonResponse();
  $response->setData($post);

  return $response;
```

Comment: В таком случае будет также выводить [{},{},{},{}]. Мне нужны данные статьи в формате json. Подобное этому: [{"id":"4","title":"firstArticle","description":"firstArticle"}]

Comment: то что я вам написал и выводит данные в формате json.

Comment: BlogBundle:Post сущность покажите и скрин с бд

Comment: @TimeToThink похожу у вас в БД просто нет записей. Попробуйте вывести массив `$posts` ещё до преобразования в json, и всё станет понятно.